Baking a Mixamo animation
I'm trying to bake an animation that was created with Mixamo, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting no errors, and this is my workflow:

I select the armature and switch to Pose Mode.
I select all the bones to bake.
I go to Object menu, then Animation, and choose Bake Action.
In the Bake Action panel, I checked Visual Keying and Clear Parents. I select Pose for Bake Data.
I click OK to bake. No error.
I go back to Object mode, select the mesh, go to the Modifiers tab and remove the Armature modifier.

The pose is lost, and there is no animation. If I apply the modifier instead of removing it, it keeps one pose, but loses the animation as well.
What am I doing wrong?



Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Sure! Here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/wm4VJzBm/

weird, it works fine for me

Can you tell me if you follow every step I outlined above, or did I miss a small detail or do something different? Are the settings the same? Thanks!

yes, I follow the same steps: https://zupimages.net/up/24/39/byop.gif

Okay, but do you also remove the Armature? Because that's when it starts to mess up for me.

Remove the armature? Why do you want to remove the armature? Baking the animation of the armature just creates a keyframe per frame and allows to get rid of the constraints but you still need the armature

I want to remove the armature, the skeleton, because the model's purpose is to be a game asset in an RTS game where hundreds of these will walk around at the same time. Losing the skeleton is an optimization effort.

if you move the armature the object won't move anymore, unless you move it with shapekeys for example but I doubt you can export shapekeys

When you export as FBX an animated character, the Armature modifier has to be present. If you want to export pure animation data you have to choose Alembic format (.abc), but it's not an optimization, as every frame is stored as an unique mesh, and it's useful only for exporting difficult scenes (simulations, particles, hair, ...)
